# How many API keys am I allowed to genetate on Google Maps API?

Tags: rest, api, google-maps

I want to know how many Google MAPs API keys we can generate?
This will allow me to have unique api key for each of the mobile devices.

Regards,

Comment: Hi there, have you tried a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+many+API+keys+am+I+allowed+to+genetate+on+Google+Maps+API)?

Comment: I don't know of a set limit for API keys but I would recommend one key per project. If you are trying to skirt their free usage limits by authorizing extra keys there is a good chance they will disable your account.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's allow only one key per Account. you can use that key in multiple project

Comment: You can have multiple keys and I would recommend one per project. You can use the same key for multiple projects, however the scope and permissions may vary so it makes sense to have different keys depending on what you are doing.